# Laravel- Trying to get property 'name' of non-object

Tags: php, html, mysql, laravel, web

estoy desarrollando un sistema de catálogo de productos con Panel de Administración en Laravel 5.5.

Ya lo he terminado y todo funciona, excepto que no puedo filtrar mis productos.

Cuando hago la función:

```
dd($products);
```

para verificar si hace el filtrado, funciona perfecto, pero cuando lo paso a vista me da el error:

**Trying to get property 'name' of non-object**

Estoy trabajando con un scope local que es este:

En el Modelo **Category.php**

```
public function scopeFilterCategory($query, $name) {
    return $query->where('name', '=', $name);
}
```

En mi vista:
**store.blade.php**

aqui es donde me genera el problema:

```
<div class="categ-buttons">
    @foreach($categories as $category)
        <ul>
            <a href="{{ route('product.filter.category', $category->name) }}">
                <li>{{ $category->name }}</li>
            </a>
        </ul>
    @endforeach
</div>
```

y mi controlador es este:

```
    public function filterCategory($name) {
    //dd($name);
    $categories = Category::FilterCategory($name)->first();
    $products = $categories->products;

    $products->each(function($products){
        $products->categories;
        $products->image;
    });

    return view('store.products', compact('products', 'categories'));

    //dd($products);
}
```

El Request de Categoria:

```
public function authorize()
{
    return true;
}

/**
 * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'name' => 'max:120|required|unique:categories',
    ];
}
```

}

Comment: Puede ser que estas devolviendo un array más no un objeto y por eso cuando imprimes nombre sale ese error.

Comment: ¿Cómo podría corregir eso?

Answer (score 1):

Efectivamente el error lo tienes en:

```
@foreach($categories as $category)
        ...

@endforeach
```

ya que estás intentado recorrer $categories como un Collection y $categories no lo es, ya que haces la consulta con un first() aquí:

```
$categories = Category::FilterCategory($name)->first();
```

Solución: Cambia la consulta por:

```
$categories = Category::FilterCategory($name)->get();
```

Comment: Ahora me lanza el siguiente error:        Property [products] dos not exist on this collection instance.       Incluso cuando intento mostrarlo usando:      dd($products).    Con first me funcionaba, solo cuando paso a la vista ocurre eso.

Comment: La variable $products la declaras aqui: $products = $categories->products; .Si $categories ahora es una Collection, no puedes hacer $categories->products.

Answer (score 0):

Amigo la forma correcta:
Editar en tu controlador:

```
$categories = Category::FilterCategory($name)->get();

return view('store.products', compact('categories'));
```

y luego en tu vista:

```
@foreach($categories as $categoria)

    @foreach($categoria->products as $producto)

    /* Aquí puedes acceder ya a toda la información y relaciones que tiene tu objeto producto  */
    
    @endforeach

@endforeach
```